# In VB.NET, is there a way to add a method call to the .load event of every Form object?

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, extension-methods

I've created an extension method to the Form class that will scale forms according to a scaling factor which is located in a database.

My problem is I am now having to go into every form and add that method to the Me.load event to implement it. Is there a way for me to make all Form objects call this method when their .load event is triggered?

Comment: Make a class that inherits from Form, implement your method on the Load of that class, and make all your form inherit from your new class.

Comment: Is there a way to make all forms automatically inherit from the new class, or will I have to go through every form to implement that as well? Thanks.

Comment: The only thing you would have to do, is to add `Inherits MyMainForm`. I cannot think of any way to make this automatic.

Comment: Thanks. I have hundreds of forms to implement. I'm doing this project as a student worker. I hope I can find a faster way.

Comment: And how are you going to find a faster way? you need each form to do something, so, the code has to come from somewhere. You create a base class and inherit - this will at least makes single location for the code. Or you can write or find existing utility that will open each .vb file and insert your code somewhere.

Comment: I was hoping I could add an event handler in a extension method that could extend the Form class or some similar solution. That doesn't seem possible though. I'm very new to this. Using a utility may be a good idea. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I hope you understand that you want to write your code in some class and then only add a call to it from a form

Comment: Borrowing from @HanletEscaño, you could do a Find & Replace Entire Solution, Find: _Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form_, Replace with _Inherits MyMainForm_. You may have to go back and fix some that you didn't intend to change. Just be sure to backup before you try this.

Comment: You could look into aspect oriented techniques to inject code at runtime. Look up PostSharp and CodeCop.